# Can't get image resize code to work in PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I am building a thumbnail system, but my code  outputs a bunch or random icons. It apparently should work, but it doesn't.

Code:

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'post/imgres/posts/1.jpg';

// Set a maximum height and width
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jepg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
$width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
$height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height,     $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

Comment: i don't think there's something like "list($width_orig, $height_orig) =" in php

Comment: @AlexisPeters Hmmm. this http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php shows it off, so i dont know.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are hundrerds of ready to use classes for your issue.

Comment: I've improved the grammar.   This question really needs more information about *what* isn't currently working.   How does this code misbehave?   What would you like it to do instead?  Can you include screen shots of the problem or example images that have been re-sized incorrectly?

Comment: `header('Content-Type: image/jepg')` – could help if you spelled jpeg correctly here …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a class called simpleimage by claviska. and my code is now done. it all looks like this.

The code that takes care of the thumbnails:

```
    function isThumb($thumbnail)
    {
        if (file_exists($thumbnail))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function makeThumb($original, $destination)
    {
        $img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage($original);
        $img->fit_to_width(256);
        $img->save($destination);
    }
    ?>
```

The code that loads the images:

```
        <?php
            //Image loader
            //Folder containing images.
            $filedir = "imgres/posts/";
            //Retrieve the images in the folder.
            $images = glob($filedir."*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}",GLOB_BRACE);
            //Make sure the image array is not empty, or null.
            if (!empty($images))
            {
                //Load the images into the website.
                foreach ($images as $image)
                {
                    if (pathinfo($image,PATINFO_EXTENSION) == "gif" || pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=="GIF") 
                    {
                        echo '<a href="'.$image.'"><img src="'.$image.'"/></a>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<a href="'.$image.'"><img src="'.getThumb($image).'"/></a>';
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Write out an error message to warn the user.
                echo "<p>No images were found in the server. This is most likely an error in the PHP code, incompatibility, or something went wrong with our storage solution. Contact admin! Information needed: Browser, OS, and has the site worked before?</p>";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: @I do code: this is what I was talking about, you got some scripts that support all image types

Answer (score 0):

PHP Image thumbnailing is a common task and there are plenty of solid image thumbnailing examples and sources are out there. I'm not sure what your script is doing but here is a barebone basic script which always works and its straight forward.

You should cover and support all image types png's and gif's. But since you're doing jpegs, let use that for now. Adding support for other image types shouldn't be that difficult.

```
/* read the source image */
$source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$width = imagesx($source_image);
$height = imagesy($source_image);

/* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
$desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

/* create a new, "virtual" image */
$virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

/* copy source image at a resized size */
imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

// Content type, you need this line of code to 
// display image to browser or for testing it on the UI
header('Content-Type: image/jepg');

/* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
```